# WindowBuilder - open a JFrame from Main

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, windowbuilder

I have a `Main.java`, here i would  only start ( set visible true )  my `JFrame` window.
But it only opens a little window without anything.
Then I would press the Highscorebutten, then a other `JFrame` (highscore) should be shown.

What should I do?

(this isn't the full code)

### Main

```
public class Main {
    private static MyWindow window = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         window = new MyWindow();
          window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          // Frame sichtbar machen
          window.setVisible(true);
    }
```

### FWindow

```
public class FWindow extends JFrame{    

private JFrame Menue;

public FWindow() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    Menue = new JFrame();
    Menue.setBounds(100, 100, 469, 741);
    Menue.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Menue.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel pMenue = new JPanel();

    pMenue.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblHighscore = new JLabel();
    lblHighscore.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
             Highscore highscore = new Highscore();         
                getContentPane().add(highscore);
                System.out.println();
                highscore.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
//........
```

### Highscore

```
public class Highscore extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTable table;
TableModel model;

public Highscore() {


    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setShowGrid(false);
    table.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
    table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
    table.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    table.setBackground(new Color(113,197,208));
    table.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    table.setRowHeight(40);
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);



    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            //.....
        },
        new String[] {
            "1", "2", "3"
        }

    ){

    });
```

.......

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1):

`FWindow` extends `JFrame`, but it is creating a second instance of `JFrame` (`Menue`), meaning you're only showing `FWindow`, which has nothing on it.

Remove the `extends JFrame` from `FWindow`, it's not adding any useful functionality

Add a method to `FWindow` which will prepare and show the `Menue` instance

```
public class FWindow {

    private JFrame Menue;

    public FWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        Menue = new JFrame();
        Menue.setBounds(100, 100, 469, 741);
        Menue.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Menue.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel pMenue = new JPanel();

        pMenue.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblHighscore = new JLabel();
        lblHighscore.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Highscore highscore = new Highscore();
                getContentPane().add(highscore);
                System.out.println();
                highscore.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        //........
    }

    public void prepareAndShow() {
        //...
        Menue.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Menue.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Then, from your `main` method, make sure you call it

```
public class Main {
    private static MyWindow window = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        window = new MyWindow();
        // Frame sichtbar machen
        window.prepareAndShow();
    }
```

As an example

*Rant warning*

Normally, I would say avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify...

But that would lead into a rant about the pros and cons of WindowBuilder ...

Basically, you are better off learning to hand code your UI's, they will give you a better appreciation for how the layout managers work and how you can achieve complex and decoupled UI's as well as a UI which will look the way you expect it to on different platforms